# Messages not working on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, messages

I am using an iPhone 5, version 9.3.2, 32 GB of memory, 27.1 of capacity.

Suddenly I cannot use my Messages.

Other option is working well but when click Messages it's just hanging.

I even cannot delete/read/send any messages.

I already powered off my phone but still same thing.

What can I do now?

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooting tips in this article? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204065

Comment: applying this troubleshooting but still same. now what i do ? @TMHahn

Comment: Hold the Home button and Power button down until you see the Apple logo, then release. Did that fix it?

Comment: After applying this method instant it was working for few second ...i just read a message then delete. Then again its goes to hanging . how fix it now ? @TMHahn

Comment: Hi Imran - I rolled back the tag in the title - the check mark in the answer lets people know you have a solution - keeping the question clear of answers helps people know to look to the answer section .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press the Home button twice. This will bring up recently used apps. Find the Message app and swipe up. This will force close the app.
2. Hold down the Power button until the power-slider appears, but don't turn the device off. Instead, while that power-slider is showing, hold down the Home button until your home screen re-appears.
3. Hold down the Home and Power buttons until the Apple Logo shows, and then release.
4. If one of your recent messages had a photo or video, try deleting it from the Messages. This may keep it from crashing again if you're able to open the app at all.

→ Try this multiple times.

If these steps still don't fix the problem, try backing up your iPhone to iTunes. Then restore from the backup. This step is tedious, I understand. But it may solve the problem when everything else has failed.

**EDIT:** 
(additional suggestions)

Going beyond what usually fixes this problem...

You're options, shy of going to an Apple Store for an actual diagnostic, would be limited at this point. I see two options.

• Restore as a new iPhone.

• Try downloading [PhoneClean](https://www.imobie.com/phoneclean/) on your computer. I have only used this briefly and am not entirely proficient in this app, but it has helped me in the past. It's available for Mac and PC.

Comment: well i will try it now

Comment: Three times i am applying this all Technics ... but its not working . still the same things . but do not understand why the only message option not working.

Comment: @imran-khan: Did you backup and restore, too? And even that didn't work?

Comment: my icloud storage almost full . For that case i am using my computer for backup . And restore the backup . Even not one time . 2 times backup and restore . But its did not work @TMHahn

Comment: Now what can i do ? @TMHahn

Comment: @ImranKhan: I edited my original response to include additional suggestions. If these do not work, you may have to go into the Apple Store for a diagnostic.