# iPod update 9.3.2. And imessaging

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

My iPod 5 (16gbs) won't let me sign into iMessage. I just updated yesterday to 9.3.2. I've tried signing and every time it says that iMessage server is unavailable. What even is that?!?! What should I do? Do I keep signing in until it works? Plus FaceTime is down. I signed into that again and it won't get it set up either. Can someone help me and tell me what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: Is this similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241702/messages-not-working-on-iphone-5 ?

Comment: @Graham It's not a duplicate of that, this question is an inability to sign in but that question is about delivery of iMessages.